# D3 Multiple Visualizations Per Page Namespace IRI Conflicts

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, xhtml

I'm using D3 to generate multiple visualizations per page, but I'm having a problem when it comes to IRIs or functional IRIs.

Namely, code with textPaths:

```
this.linkGroup.selectAll(".text_path")
 .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#" + d.id })
 .text(function(d) { return d.text })
```

or markers:

```
this.linkGroup.selectAll(".link")
  .attr("marker-start", function(d) { return "url(#startArrow)" })
```

With both of these, if any SVG I create after the first has the same IRI id as a previous one, it will use the first id found in the HTML, even if that is from a different SVG than the current context.
As an example:

```
<body>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <marker id="startArrow"...>...</marker>
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <marker id="startArrow"...>...</marker>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</body>
```

If in the second SVG I reference the marker with `url(#startArrow)`, it will instead get the first `#startArrow` in the entire document, in this case, the first SVG.

Is there a way to use only the ids/IRIs within the current SVG instead of the entire document? Not sure if this would require some namespacing or not.

Comment: ^So the answer is a no, it's actually impossible, sadly... should've realized since ids are meant to be one per page.